# android:protectionLevel "signature" with multiple certificates

Tags: android

i've 2 android applications.

The first one "A" will be signed with 2 certificates:

- C_1
- C_2

"A" have broadcastreceiver with the permission setted to android:protectionLevel="signature" and it has a shared User id with a system process which has been signed with C_1.

The second Application "B" wants to use this broadcast receiver.

Now, i've the complete control on the C_2 certificate and a third party agency would sign the "A" application with the C_1 certificate. For now i'm using the android debug certificate instead of C_1

I've done some kind of tests in order to see what happens in the following scenarios:

- If i sign "A" with C_1 and "B" with C_1 everything works
- If i sign "A" with both (in order) C_1 and C_2 , and i sign "B" with C_2 it does not work
- If i sign "A" with both (in order) C_2 and C_1 , and i sign "B" with C_2 it does not work
- If i sign "A" with both ( no matter what order ) C_1 and C_2, and i sign "B" with C_1 **it does work!**

I think that the sharedUid things in the manifest is causing problems.

I'm working with an android 2.1-update1 device.

Any little help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Nervermind that you can't get two certificates to work, what are you trying to do... share data across apps?

Comment: Nope, i need the "A" application to do some things via the broadcast intent. Since "A" shares the same User ids of the com.android.phone process i want to enable this broadcastreceiver only for allowed applications. I thought the best way to achieve this was using the protectionlevel thing.

Comment: Have you looked into using ContentProvider?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked quite a long time ago, but for future readers we can see the AOSP source (specifically `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/PermissionManagerServiceImpl.java`) for a detailed set of conditions:

```java
private boolean shouldGrantPermissionBySignature(@NonNull AndroidPackage pkg,
    @NonNull Permission bp) {
// expect single system package
String systemPackageName = ArrayUtils.firstOrNull(mPackageManagerInt.getKnownPackageNames(
        KnownPackages.PACKAGE_SYSTEM, UserHandle.USER_SYSTEM));
final AndroidPackage systemPackage =
        mPackageManagerInt.getPackage(systemPackageName);
// check if the package is allow to use this signature permission.  A package is allowed to
// use a signature permission if:
//     - it has the same set of signing certificates as the source package
//     - or its signing certificate was rotated from the source package's certificate
//     - or its signing certificate is a previous signing certificate of the defining
//       package, and the defining package still trusts the old certificate for permissions
//     - or it shares a common signing certificate in its lineage with the defining package,
//       and the defining package still trusts the old certificate for permissions
//     - or it shares the above relationships with the system package
final SigningDetails sourceSigningDetails =
        getSourcePackageSigningDetails(bp);
return sourceSigningDetails.hasCommonSignerWithCapability(
                pkg.getSigningDetails(),
                SigningDetails.CertCapabilities.PERMISSION)
        || pkg.getSigningDetails().hasAncestorOrSelf(systemPackage.getSigningDetails())
        || systemPackage.getSigningDetails().checkCapability(
                pkg.getSigningDetails(),
                SigningDetails.CertCapabilities.PERMISSION);
}
```

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/refs/heads/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/PermissionManagerServiceImpl.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=3384